# springboot JPA very slow compared to SQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have a springboot app and a postgresql DB attached to it. I have a table with 40 mio records. The table is quite simple : ID, name (varchar), x (numeric), y (numeric).

I have to query this table like that : select * from table where x < maxX and x > minX and y < maxY and y > minY

I already created indexes on X and Y.

If I query the DB from a desktop client (for instance DBeaver) it tooks ~700ms to fetch the data, which is quite acceptable for my need.

But if I query from my springboot app (through a REST endpoint), it tooks 1 minute (!) which is a way too slow.

I can easily understand that it would be slower through my springboot app than through a DB client (because of the latency between the DB and the app, the ORM, the conversion to JAVA, etc...) but more than 70x slower is quite strange, isn't it ?

I want to drastically reduce that process time, do you have any idea how to do it ?

The method of my jpa repository looks like this :

```
@Query(value = "select * from table a where a.x < :maxX and a.x > :minX and a.y < :maxY and a.y > :minY", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyEntity> getMyEntityByXY(@Param("maxX") Double maxX, @Param("minX") Double minX, @Param("maxY") Double maxY, @Param("minY") Double minY);
```

I tried with "standard" jpa query and with this native query since it is the closest to the query that tooks 700ms through the DB client.

I had the idea to use parallel query but it does not sound like a suitable solution and I did not manage to do it with postgresql (I know the /* parallel(32) */ way with Oracle for instance but I can't manage to do it with postgres).

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell unless you would provide more information, like how does your entity mapping looks like. If I had to guess I would say that either something not-needed was eagerly fetched, or something needed was lazily fetched. If you wan't to understand better why was hibernate query so slow, you could also set 'spring.jpa.show-sql` flag to true in application.properties, this way, each executed sql statement will be logged.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped JPA & Hibernate and I only use a raw JDBC template with custom mapping (through RowMapper) and I have now approximately the same performances as my DB client (DBeaver).

Is it the best way to improve the performances of my springboot app ?